# Visual Studio compilation error finding file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I don't understand why my code won't compile. I saw another post that had the same issue, but their problem was not using #include  and not using namespace std, both of which I have. Anyone know why?? p.s. my code is NOT finished, but I want to make it work before I get any further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//Function prototypes to warn main function
void readData(int num);
void oddTally(int num);
void oddSum(int num);
void oddAverage(double num);
void evenTally(int num);
void evenSum(int num);
void evenAverage(double num);
void displayNames(string name1, string name2);

int main()
{
int inData, oTally, oSum, eTally, eSum;
double oAverage, eAverage;
string name1, name2;

ifstream inFile;
readData(inData);
oddTally(oTally);
oddSum(oSum);
oddAverage(oAverage);
evenTally(eTally);
evenSum(eSum);
evenAverage(eAverage);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
void readData(int num)
{
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("in.txt");
int inData;

//Read the data.
if (inFile)
{
    while (inFile >> inData)
    {
        cout << inData << '\n';
    }
}
else
{
    //Displays error message.
    cout << "Error opening the file. \n";
}
}
```

Comment: It didn't occur to you to post the error messages?

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

to use `system`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that none of your variables is initalized but you try to pass them by value.  This would result in udnefined behaviour, and this is why Visual studio complains.

Just initialize each of your variabl (for example `=0`) before using it.